# Removing a node in a linked list

Tags: java, nodes, doubly-linked-list

Trying to remove a node by index now. I'd like to print out the list of nodes with indices so the user can select the index as seen. I think my logic is okay in printing the list with the indices but no input is coming out :(

At one point in fooling around with this, I was still unable to print the list of nodes but the "enter in the index you wish to delete" was output  and was able to take a users' selection but eventually got a NullPointerException.

```
            else if (menu.equals("d")) {
            EntryNode temp = head;
            while (temp != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < addressBook.length(); i++) {
                    //gets node at index
                    System.out.println(temp.getFirstName() + i);
                    temp = temp.getNext();
                }
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("Please enter the index of the entry you wish to delete ");
            int index = keyboard.nextInt();
            addressBook.removeEntry(index);
            }

        }
```

The removal method:
        public void removeEntry(int index){

```
    //delete from the head
    if (index == 0) {
        EntryNode temp = head;
        head = temp.getNext();
        temp.setNext(null);
        head.setPrev(null);
        size--;
    }
    //delete from the tail
    else if (index == length()) {
        EntryNode temp = tail;
        temp.setPrev(null);
        tail.setNext(null);
        tail = temp.getPrev();

        size--;
    }
    //in the middle
    else {
        EntryNode temp = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            //gets node at index
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        //set node after temp's previous to temp's previous 
        temp.getNext().setPrev(temp.getPrev());
        temp.getPrev().setNext(temp.getNext());
        temp.setNext(null);
        temp.setPrev(null);
        size--;
    }
}
```

The NullPointerException comes from :

```
//set node after temp's previous to temp's previous 
temp.getNext().setPrev(temp.getPrev());
```

Comment: Shouldn't `else if (index == length()) {` be `else if (index == length() -1 ) {` instead? If you start indexing from 0 and `length()` is the number of elements, the index of the tail will be `length() - 1` and not `length()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if `temp.getNext()` is not `null` before calling the `setPrev()` on it.

Also, you should check with `length()-1` as you have nodes which are zero indexed.

Comment: If temp.getNext() is null, isn't temp tail then?

Comment: Yes, but if you do your null checks properly, you won't have to have a special case for head and tail.

Comment: @JackieAldama Yes. Its going to `in the middle` block because your length is probably not correct (Is it returning `actual-length` (then modify your condition) or `actual-length - 1`?).

Comment: Okay I updated this to if, else statement to check if temp==head, temp.getNext() == null, or else...

Comment: Regarding the first part of the question though, is there something clearly wrong with the way I am trying to output the list with indices for user input?

Comment: Yes. You should either have `while (temp != null) {` or `for (int i = 0; i < addressBook.length(); i++) {` but not both. I would prefer to have the first one.

Comment: How would I get the index (i) AND check that temp.getNext isn't null then?

Comment: 1. You can just initialize `i=0` before the beginning of `while` and increment it every time in the loop. 2. You don't need to check if `temp.getNext` is null or not. Also, you would probably want to keep the `Syso`s, `int in...` and `ad...` out of the `while` loop.

Comment: That's what I figured. So i added a counter = 0; and then the while(temp!=null) { print out temp, temp = temp.getNext() and increment counter. Still, only What is outside of the loop is what gets printed (ie. System... int index.. ad..)

Comment: Then probably your `head` is `null` to begin with.

Comment: Ahhh. Head is null when things start out but I am testing this with nodes added into the linked list.

Comment: But when you add the nodes into the linked list, do you update `head` to point to the first node of the list?

Comment: Yes, is this because all of this is in the main method, not in the "AddressList" class? grr..

Answer (score 1):

Indices are in the range `[0, length() - 1]`, so you should use

```
else if (index == length() - 1) {
```

instead.